# Adding a line in a diagram using tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, tikz-trees

Currently my diagram looks like this:

[image: Diagram]

Using the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=8cm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.50cm},level 3/.style={sibling distance=1.50cm}]
    \node {Statistical Testing}[edge from parent fork down]
            child { node {External Criteria}
                child { node {Rand Statistic}}
                child { node { Jaccard Coefficient}}
                child { node {Folkes and Mallows Index}}
                child { node {Hubert's $\Gamma$ statistic}}
                child { node {Normalized $\Gamma$ statistic}}
                  }
            child { node {Internal Criteria}
                child { node {Cophenetic Correlation Coefficient}}
                child { node {Hubert's $\Gamma$ statistic}}
                child { node {Normalized $\Gamma$ statistic}}
                  }
              ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

How would I go about adding a line in-between Rand & statistic and all others so I have enough space to fit this diagram?

I've tried adding a \ between the two but I get an error.

Comment: Thanks! I've checked your answer too and just what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `text width` of the nodes, then there will be automatic line breaks, and this can allow you to avoid the nodes from overlapping. I personally would use forest for such diagrams. **EDIT**: Fixed `overfull hboxes`, big thanks to @cfr!!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage[edges]{forest} % for the second part of the anser
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=7.3cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=1.8cm,text width=1.8cm,level distance=2.8cm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=1.50cm}]
    \node {Statistical Testing}[edge from parent fork down]
            child { node {External Criteria}
                child { node {Rand Statistic}}
                child { node {\hskip0ptJaccard Coefficient}}
                child { node {Folkes and Mallows Index}}
                child { node {Hubert's $\Gamma$ statistic}}
                child { node {\hskip0ptNormalized $\Gamma$ statistic}}
                  }
            child { node {Internal Criteria}
                child { node {\hskip0ptCophenetic Correlation Coefficient}}
                child { node {Hubert's $\Gamma$ statistic}}
                child { node {\hskip0ptNormalized $\Gamma$ statistic}}
                  }
              ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
where level=2{text width=1.7cm}{},
for tree={s sep=1pt}
[Statistical Testing
            [External Criteria
                [Rand Statistic]
                [Jaccard Coefficient]
                [Folkes and Mallows Index]
                [Hubert's $\Gamma$ statistic]
                [\hskip0ptNormalized $\Gamma$ statistic]
                 ]
            [Internal Criteria
                [\hskip0ptCophenetic Correlation Coefficient]
                [Hubert's $\Gamma$ statistic]
                [\hskip0ptNormalized $\Gamma$ statistic]
                  ]
]                 
\end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you get bad box warnings? :-) You need to add to the start of the node content so TeX agrees to split the first word in the node. E.g. `align={@{\hskip0pt}p{12mm}@{}}` or `+content=\hskip0pt` or whatever.

Comment: @cfr Absolutely! You're right!